# No Install group file - CentOS 7 - group install

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, yum

I am using CentOS image inside a docker container every `yum install <package-name>` works but when i try to run

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

it just raise error saying:

> There is no installed groups file. Maybe run: yum groups mark convert
>   (see man yum)

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Starting from base CentOS image
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum groupinstall -y "Development tools"
```

Can some one suggest possible solution to this? I have never experienced any such issue in normal CentOS but seen that first time in docker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing the following may work, and is consistent with your error message:

```
yum groups mark install "Development Tools"
yum groups mark convert "Development Tools"
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Source: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1262603